# Git status gives me gitignores files - why?

Tags: git, composer-php

Don't know why git status shows me all untracked files after "git status" as "tracked filed"

```
mkdir test
cd test 
git init
git remote add origin ORIGINURL
git fetch
git branch -b 'local_develop' origin/'develop'
ls -l 
/vendor/ 
.gitignore # .gitignore contains here /vendor/ 

composer install 
git status 

# I'm getting here list like:  
# deleted: vendor/file1.php
# deleted: vendor/file2.php
```

Why is that? I do not want to see any information in my git status related to ignored files.

Comment: timsmelik is correct... but he doesn't tell you what to do about it.  Very simply: `git rm -r --cached <folder>`.  Look here for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1274447/421195

Answer (score 2):

The listed files are probably already tracked.

Check the official [.gitignore documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore):

> A gitignore file specifies intentionally untracked files that Git should ignore. Files already tracked by Git are not affected; see the NOTES below for details.

From the same page:

> To stop tracking a file that is currently tracked, use `git rm --cached`.

Comment: I know that. That is why i provided full code example starts from"git init" how it's possible that git tracked files before "git init" i also tested before "composer install" i manually added file to vendor dir and after my manuall change i did not see any changes in "git status"

Comment: @user88831 But you said `git fetch` and `git branch -b 'local_develop' origin/'develop'`. Those files were already in the remote repo, and now, presto, they are in _your_ repo and _your_ index. It doesn’t matter whether you ignore them now; it’s too late. They are present and tracked. You are punching yourself in the face and then complaining that someone is punching your face. :)

Comment: "Those files were already in the remote repo, and now, presto, they are in your repo and your index. It doesn’t matter whether you ignore them now; it’s too late. " . 
So that would be correct way of init this repo?

Comment: After "gir rm -r -cached vendor". I see those files as "green". I have to make commit now, i would prefer get them disappear from my index of them without any commit.